# Giving Node.js access to certificate/private key

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am trying to use HTTPS on my Node.js app, just as it is already enabled for anything else. I have the keys and certificates already installed, but I get a `Error: EACCES, permission denied` when I tried to point to them on the app.

Both the key and the certificate are in subfolder of `/etc/pki/tls`, and I attempted pointing to them like this:

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/tls/private/serverKey.key').toString(),
    certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/tls/certs/2_mikewarren.me.crt').toString();

var options = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}
```

Do I need to adjust the permissions of the keys and certificates (via `chown`)? If so, is it safe to do?

Comment: Why not just move the files to the directory where your node.js code is?  You know the node.js process has the rights to read that directory and you know that directory is protected from outside access, right?

Comment: @jfriend00 copy them?

Comment: They're files in your OS.  You can just move those files to the appropriate directory.  If you're using them for your https server, you aren't presumably using them for other things.  Or put them in better shared location that all things who need access can get access.

Comment: I am using them for phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got my code access.

**What I did**

1. created new user group called `certAccess`
2. added myself to `certAccess` by saying `sudo useradd ec2-user -G certAccess`
3. added root user (who was the only user with access to those files) to `certAccess`
4. changed the owner of the private key: `sudo chown ec2-user.certAccess /etc/pki/tls/private/serverKey.key`

**Testing...**

To test, I simply print `options` to the console, right after using it. Indeed, I saw the contents of private key and certificate (try it yourself). I also restart `httpd` server, and requested static files. I saw them, protected with TLS, without fault.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that these certificates are only readable by root (and maybe an other user).

You could use chmod to give read access to all users, but that means… that all users would have access to it. So, bad idea.

An other solution would be to either `chown` these files to the user running node.js, but if there is already a user with an application using these, it will break it. In that case, create a new group that owns the file, give read permissions to that group, and add the users that should access the files in that group.

Comment: How to do this? For example, how to create groups?

Comment: I created the group to access the certificate (in the server's specified directory). Now how do I change permissions for the group to access it? I want to be able to have SSL/TLS whether my node.js code is running or not

Comment: with chown and chmod

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but my solution is slightly different than `MikeWarren`'s

1. Create new user group called `certAccess`

- `sudo groupadd certAccess`

2. Add existing users to `certAccess` group

- `sudo usermod -a -G certAccess YOUR_USER`

3. Inorder to activate user groups `logout` and `login` again
4. Change group ownership of cert files or if you have more than one certificate change folder ownership recursively.

- `sudo chown -R root:certAccess /etc/letsencrypt/live/`
- `sudo chown -R root:certAccess /etc/letsencrypt/archive/`

5. Default cert files have mod `744`, Node.js `readFileSync()` can't execute cert files so add `execute` permission to group by changing mod to `754`.

- `sudo chmod -R 754 /etc/letsencrypt/live/`
- `sudo chmod -R 754 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/`

Done.