# Encrypting content sent with Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get HTTPS up on my node.js application. I [made progress on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557213/giving-node-js-access-to-certificate-private-key) by creating `certAccess` group that contains both `root` and `ec2-user`, and then saying `sudo chown ec2-user.certAccess /etc/pki/tls/private/serverKey.key`. However, when I run this dummy code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var app = require('express')();
var options = {
   key  : fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/tls/private/serverKey.key').toString(),
   cert : fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/tls/certs/2_mikewarren.me.crt').toString()
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World!');
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8080, function () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(options, null, '\t'));
   console.log('Started!');
});
```

and test it out in my browser (use `<yourDomain>:8080`), I get no response from server.

I go in and see the permissions of my private key and certificate, and see this:

[image: Permissions for key,certificate]

The private key and certificate configuration, located in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` looks like: [image]

However, when I do the test in my browser (even typing `https://` in front of the URL, which I shouldn't have to), I get no response from server.

What should I do?!?!?

Comment: I don't know if this is the source of your problem, but I see two things.  1) You can't just do <yourDomain>:8080.  You have to include the `https` as in `https://yourdomain.com:8080`.  And, 2) remove the `.toString()` after both the `readFileSync()` calls.  Certificates are not strings.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. It simply requests content as if the server was off.

Comment: Yes.  Those are both valid fixes.  You apparently have more things wrong that just that.  You apparently have errors going on somewhere.  You will have to do some debugging to see exactly what is happening on both the server and the client to see why no connection is established.  I don't think there is enough disclosed in your question for us to know what is happening.

Comment: Months ago, I followed [these instructions][1] to get the certificate installed (certificate was obtained thanks to some friendly agent at StartCOM), and the other day, when I finally got to making this accessible to my node.js code, I changed permissions (as mentioned above). The code itself, is from the Learning Node.js book by Marc Wandschneider, which is also accessible [here][2]

[1]: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html#ssl_test
[2]: https://github.com/marcwan/LearningNodeJS/blob/master/Chapter10/05a_https_builtin/https_express_server.js

Comment: What the hell? It won't hyperlink properly!!

Comment: Comment markdown is slightly different than post markdown. Just use `[link text](link url)`. Regarding the question, though, what messages do you see when you start the server? Any errors/warnings or just the options JSON and "Started!"?

Comment: Just the ´options´ JSON and "Started!"

Comment: More information about the certificate configuration (found in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`)

http://imgur.com/a/x9FT4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with solution. Here's what I did:

I added `ca` member to `options` and pointed to that chain cert as it, like this: `ca   : fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/tls/certs/1_root_bundle.crt', 'utf8')`. That solves the cert problem. As for the next part, I simply wrote line in BASH that redirects https (port 443) to the port I was using (which I, out of convenience, changed to 8443, because I already redirected http to 8080).

That got it working, but it still sucks that I have to still prefix URL with `https://`. I shouldn't have to! I think solution to that is to do what I already have done, but redirect http to port 8443, or proxy port  8080 to port 8443.