# Nodejs ssl key permission denied

Tags: node.js, linux, lets-encrypt

I am getting this error when trying to access my ssl key and cetificate from my nodejs app:

[image]

As you can see, I've added my user to hace permission on the files.. I don't know what else to do?

Comment: I have this problem too, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 16):

Ok, I found the solution looking around.

Basically, LetsEncrypt is generating the certificate files in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/` and `/etc/letsencrypt/archive/`. These two folders have permissions 744 ("owner can read, write, and execute; group and users can read"), but it is not enough: you must give permissions to read and execute:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt/live/
sudo chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/
```

This is of course not a good solution for security reasons, but it's the only one I found that works, and surely it's better than running the Node.js server as root!

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/node-red/g8cPmNgGnh0/guWq-8szBAAJ

Comment: I don't think there is a better solution, Debian uses a group called `ssl-cert` for the default key file `/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` and it is suggested like this here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557213/giving-node-js-access-to-certificate-private-key/38794450#38794450
But the key file should have permissions like 640 (or 740 or 750 for your examples), for security reasons you should not give permission to read to all users like you did.

Comment: I added -R param so will do recursive chmod

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem and if you are running nodejs as ubuntu user (in case you are on amazon AWS and EC2), do not set 777 chmod on your let's encrypt certs.

All you need to do is allow **ubuntu** user to access them.

```
sudo chown ubuntu -R /etc/letsencrypt
```

Node app ran with **ubuntu** user will now have access to those certs. You can create another user and run NodeJS app with it and allow access to certs too (read only)

Comment: I think it's just good in general to not set ANYTHING 777.  If you find yourself doing that, then you should back up and find out where you went wrong!  :-D

Answer (score -1):

You can try `su -i` or `sudu su` or `sudo -s` and then `cd {DIR}`.